# Images on swift

Tags: swift, command-line

I'm working with the command line tool in Xcode using Swift 2.0. I'm new to this language and I mainly used c#. in c# when you want to load an image from the hard drive to your program you can simply use Image.ImageFromFileName(file_adress), and then save it as a bitmap wand work on it. I searched for something like that in swift and found nothing. is there a way to do so?
Again I'm not programming apps for OS X or iOS just using the command line tool.

Comment: Swift can't open images itself. You need Cocoa or Cocoa-touch for this. You can open files with `NSData(contentsOfFile: ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to convert images from whatever format to `.bmp`, you can use Automator, no programming required.

But if you want to do it in Swift:

```
import Cocoa

let image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/path/to/image.jpg")!
let bitmapRep = image.representations[0] as! NSBitmapImageRep
let data = bitmapRep.representationUsingType(.NSBMPFileType, properties: [:])!

data.writeToFile("/path/to/output.bmp", atomically: true)
```